# Finding a vector that is orthogonal to two other vectors

Tags: linear-algebra

Say that
**j** = \begin{pmatrix} 2 \\ 5 \\ -1 \end{pmatrix} and **k** = \begin{pmatrix} -6 \\ 4 \\ -3 \end{pmatrix}
There are two nonzero 3D vectors
**a** = \begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \\ z \end{pmatrix},
which are orthogonal to both **j** and **k**, such that vector **a**'s entries $x$, $y$, and $z$ are integers which satisfy $\gcd(x,y,z) = 1$. Find either vector.

I can't think of any other way to do this than trial and error, which I think would be too messy and too time-consuming. What method should I approach this problem with?

Comment: Are you familiar with vector calculus or perhaps linear algebra?

Comment: Find the cross-product of **j** with **k**, then of **k** with **j**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the cross product to find such $a$ (except for the multiplication of a possible constant) or just write the system of equation:

$a$ orthogonal to $j$ is the same as saying that the dot product is zero, therefore:

$$2x+5y-z=0 $$

The same with $a$ orthogonal with k$

$$-6x+4y-3z=0$$

Therefore:

$y=-\frac{12x}{11}$

And $z=2x+5y=2x-\frac{60x}{11}=\frac{38x}{11}$

You want the solutions to be integers with gcd 1. Take $x=11$ then $y=-12$ and $z=38$.

Answer (score 0):

The orthogonal vectors have to has the same direction as the vector 
$$ v = \begin{pmatrix}
    \det
    \begin{pmatrix}
      4 & -3 \\
      5 & -1
    \end{pmatrix},
    -\det
    \begin{pmatrix}
      -6 & -3 \\
      2 & -1
    \end{pmatrix},
    \det
    \begin{pmatrix}
      -6 & 4 \\
      2 & 5
    \end{pmatrix}
   \end{pmatrix}
$$

$v$ is the [cross product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product) of $k$ and $j$.